# Bootstrap mobile preview screen using Adobe CQ 5.5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, handlebars.js, aem

I am using CQ 5.5 at work and am required to create a mobile preview screen.

I have used extjs dialog form for creating assets in repository. These assets get served via a web service to IOS and android apps.

I need to follow this up with having a feature to preview this data for mobile usage.

I have two spikes - one using handlebar js that pulls the data in the screen using regex and then displays it. The other being boostrap to display responsive screen OUTSIDE cq.

Any assistance for achieving the mobile preview screen would be great. Things I have created using the dialog are slideshow, images, datefield and text. I would like to put this into a small mobile preview screen. That can be modal or an iframe.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you are attempting to do. Are you tring to create a web page that displays assets as if they are on a mobile appliance, or create a web page to view from a mobile appliance?

Comment: the former is what i want - web page that displays assets as if they are on a mobile appliance

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve the solution by using two separate divs for displaying phone content and desktop content. Below is the code for those who might find this helpful. Respect to this site as it has

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
                  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
              </head>
            <body style="margin:0;padding:0;">

              <div id="container">

                <div id="switch">
                  <span id="data" class="active">DESKTOP</span>
                  <span id="preview">PHONE</span>
                </div>

                <div id="phonebezel" style="display:none;">

                  <div id="phonet-content">

                    <div id="toolbar">
                      <h1 id="title"><cq:text property="title"/></h1>
                   </div>

                  <div class="medicine--large">

                            <div class="medicine-name"><cq:text property="title"/></div>

                              <span class="checkmark"><img src="../contentmedicine-script/images/sample.png" width="18" height="18"></span>





                          <div class="description">

                            <h3><cq:text property="medicine-description"/></h3>

                          </div>

                  </div> 

                </div>

                <div id="meta-tags">

                  <div class="medicine--image">
                    <img src="<%= properties.get("medicineFileReference", "#") %>" width="320" height="480" />
                  </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

              <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                   $('#data').click(function(){
                      $(this).addClass('active');
                      $('#preview').removeClass('active');
                      $('#phonebezel').hide();
                      $('#meta-tags').fadeIn('slow');
                   });

                    $('#preview').click(function(){
                      $(this).addClass('active');
                      $('#data').removeClass('active');
                      $('#meta-tags').hide();
                      $('#phonebezel').fadeIn('slow');
                   });


                 });
              </script>
```

Comment: PLEASE UPVOTE THE SOLUTION IF YOU FIND THIS HELPFUL